# Can you Subquery Based on a Lookup Field?

Tags: omnistudio, vlocity, subquery

I have a relationship between Census Members and Quoted Plan Rate Breakout records based on a lookup field.  My subquery is failing.  In SOQL are you able to subquery records based on a look-up field, or does it need to be master-detail?

```
SELECT vlocity_ins__FirstName__c, Middle_Initial__c, vlocity_ins__LastName__c, Relationship__c,  vlocity_ins__PrimaryMemberIdentifier__c,
  (SELECT Premium__c FROM Quote_Line_Item_Members__r)

FROM vlocity_ins__GroupCensusMember__c
WHERE vlocity_ins__CensusId__c IN(SELECT vlocity_ins__GroupCensusId__c FROM Quote WHERE id = '0Q0R0000000KEC4KAO') and Relationship__c = 'Employee'
ORDER BY
vlocity_ins__PrimaryMemberIdentifier__c,
vlocity_ins__IsPrimaryMember__c DESC,
vlocity_ins__IsSpouse__c DESC,
Age__c DESC
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a subquery on both lookup and master-detail relationships.

In your example, you are using a relationship from a managed package so will need to add the namespace to the relationship field: `(SELECT Premium__c FROM vlocity_ins__Quote_Line_Item_Members__r)`

It is confusing because Salesforce does not make it obvious when you need to do that!

(If `Premium__c` is not your own field and from the package, you'll need to add it there too)

Comment: Fred, this is perfect, thank you.  This worked.